# ImageCopy output color

Tags: php

i try to merge two images using php. after i did, the output color not same with the origin.
whats wrong with my code?

image 1

[image]

image 2

[image]

output

[image]

this is my code

```
$top_file = '1.png';
$bottom_file = '2.png';
$top = imagecreatefrompng($top_file);
$bottom = imagecreatefrompng($bottom_file);

// get current width/height
list($top_width, $top_height) = getimagesize($top_file);
list($bottom_width, $bottom_height) = getimagesize($bottom_file);

// compute new width/height
$new_width = ($top_width > $bottom_width) ? $top_width : $bottom_width;
$new_height = $top_height + $bottom_height;

// create new image and merge
$new = imagecreate($new_width, $new_height);
imagecopy($new, $top, 0, 0, 0, 0, $top_width, $top_height);
imagecopy($new, $bottom, 0, $top_height+1, 0, 0, $bottom_width, $bottom_height);

// save to file
imagepng($new, 'merged_image.png');
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Niet the Dark Absol says, you need `imagecreatetruecolor` instead of `imagecreate`. However, you need some more steps to preserve the transparecy. Key functions include `imagesavealpha` and `imagefill`. The former one preserves transparency, and the latter puts a transparent background on the newly created image. Here is a working copy:

```
$top_file = '1.png';
$bottom_file = '2.png';
$top = imagecreatefrompng($top_file);
$bottom = imagecreatefrompng($bottom_file);

// get current width/height
list($top_width, $top_height) = getimagesize($top_file);
list($bottom_width, $bottom_height) = getimagesize($bottom_file);

// compute new width/height
$new_width = ($top_width > $bottom_width) ? $top_width : $bottom_width;
$new_height = $top_height + $bottom_height;

// create new image and merge
$new = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
imagesavealpha($new, true);

$trans_colour = imagecolorallocatealpha($new, 0, 0, 0, 127);
imagefill($new, 0, 0, $trans_colour);

imagecopy($new, $top, 0, 0, 0, 0, $top_width, $top_height);
imagecopy($new, $bottom, 0, $top_height+1, 0, 0, $bottom_width, $bottom_height);

// save to file
imagepng($new, 'merged_image.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

Images created with `imagecreate` are palette-based and therefore limited to 256 colours. You have highly gradiented images. Use `imagecreatetruecolor` instead.